# header("location:signin.html"); not at all working on live server

Tags: php, html, header

I have tried out some code for logout for destroying session and via headder redirecting to another page..!!but redirection not at all happning..!plzz help me out..!!

**form.php**

```
 <a href="sign_out.php">Sign out</a>
```

**sign_out.php**

```
     <?php   
session_start(); //to ensure you are using same session
session_destroy(); //destroy the session
header('Location: signin.html'); //to redirect back to "index.php" after logging out
?>
```

Comment: please comment your echo "you have

Comment: Please correct your echo statement by `echo "you have";`, There is no need to echo before header() So comment it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php   
session_start(); //to ensure you are using same session
session_destroy(); //destroy the session
header("location:test.html"); //to redirect back to "index.php" after logging out
?>
```

Try this way I have tested it on my end.

Comment: sir..!! i have updated my script even though its not working in godaddy server..!!

Comment: Hi Krishna, Please put ob_start(); in your first line and check with above code. and let me know

Comment: one small question..!! while starting session_start(); is ob_start(); required..??

Answer (score 0):

See below:

```
<?php   
session_start(); //to ensure you are using same session
session_destroy(); //destroy the session
//echo "you have //just comment this echo
header("location:signin.html"); //to redirect back to "index.php" after logging out
exit();
?>
```

Comment: Can't "echo" before a "header()"

Comment: Updated the answer. Thanks, I did not know that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all chnage `echo "you have` to `echo "you have";`. You can't `echo` anything before `header()` in PHP. If you are outputting anything before header then it will give an error.

And if you want to echoing anything before and then also you need to redirect in specific condition then use `<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href='your_full_url';`

Answer (score 0):

Header return error if you write echo before it. So if you use herder then not use echo if you want to echo anything then use `<script>` like below.

```
echo "<script>window.location='signin.html';</script>";
```

Please try and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If have `echo` before header sent to client, it's error. I think you dont display error or warning. Remove `echo "you have logged out";`
if you turnning on log for error and warning, you can see: cannot modify header information - headers already sent by ...

Answer (score 0):

Remove any white space before `<?php` opening tag and add `exit()` at the end of the script, it will force to redirect.

```
<?php   //remove white space before this tag
session_start(); //to ensure you are using same session
session_destroy(); //destroy the session
header('Location: signin.html'); //to redirect back to "index.php" after logging out
exit();
?>
```